# Wordpress - it works, but I don't know why

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm writing a custom theme from scratch. As a menu, I use the jquery accordion control; each accordion item content is loaded using jquery.load(), as it follows:

```
function accordion_show(divID, cat){
        $("#" + divID).addClass("aLoaderShow");
        $("#" + divID).load("<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/wp-content/themes/peng2/menu-content.php?q=" + cat);
        $("#" + divID).show();
        $("#" + divID).removeClass("aLoaderShow");
    }
```

I have also enabled mod_rewrite to get pretty posts permalinks.

I can't understand why the script works only if I leave two blank lines at the top of menu-content.php.

I mean:

```
 <?php 
       $category = $_GET["q"];
       ...
```

it doesn't work. But:

```
(blank line)
(blank line) 
<?php 
       $category = $_GET["q"];
       ...
```

it works! It's a kind of magic?

Comment: correct the type `<$php ` `<?php`

Comment: In your version that works, do you get "*header already sent*" or "*cannot modify header*" errors? Just a longshot, but if you do get these messages, the likely cause is you have some syntax error somewhere that can't be reached if you add those blank lines?

Comment: In what way does it not work without the blank lines? Fails to load completely? Doesn't display correctly?

Comment: @roryf - I get a 404 error on the GET function (I'm using Chrome Developer Tools script inspector).

Comment: @Mosaul - sorry but I can't understand your question.

Comment: @franz - in what context is the accordion_show function? Is this within <script> tags in a PHP file? Is it in a JS file?
@Musaul - Great thought! @Franz - look in the console within the dev tools to see if there is anything like 'header already sent' or 'cannot modify header' errors. Also, I'd add this to wp-config.php to get better error reporting `define('WP_DEBUG', true)`.

Comment: What I was trying to say is that ... you may have a syntax error somewhere that causes your script to fail. This code with the error is processes AFTER the file containing the script you posted. But between those two points some code is trying to set a field in the header. If you add those two blank lines, the header can no longer be modified, so PHP stops before reaching the error, giving you a working, but partial response. *Just a theory.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what you mean by "it works", it's impossible to give a full answer.

However, if I were to take a guess, I would say that the reason why you *think* it works with carriage returns is because the two carriage returns at the top of your file now means that the AJAX call receives data instead of nothing at all, which could be the original reason why it was not working.

This suggests something is wrong in your PHP script i.e. it's not echoing out the value it's supposed to. However, without being able to see what the rest of your PHP script does, I can't tell for certain.